# Implementar una función de JavaScript en un formulario de extensión blade.php

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel, laravel-8

Tengo una función que me calcula el año de nacimiento en JavaScript:

```
function calculateAge(birthday) {
    var birthday_arr = birthday.split("/");
    var birthday_date = new Date(birthday_arr[2], birthday_arr[1] - 1, birthday_arr[0]);
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday_date.getTime();
    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs);
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}

var age = calculateAge("15/04/1976");
alert( age );
```

Esta función he de implementarla en un formulario para calcular la diferencia de edad entre la fecha de nacimiento y la actual:

```
@csrf
<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label for="dni">DNI<br></label>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="dni" value="{{ old('dni', $cliente->dni)}}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label for="nombre"></label>
        <br>Nombre del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="nombre" value="{{ old('nombre', $cliente->nombre)}}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label for="apellidos"></label>
        <br>Apellidos del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="apellidos" value="{{ old('apellidos', $cliente->apellidos) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label for="fechana"></label>
        <br>Fecha de Nacimiento<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="date" id="fechana" name="fechana" value="{{ old('fechana', $cliente->fechana)}}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Url para el cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="url" value="{{ old('url', $cliente->url) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Codigo Postal del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="codigopostal" value="{{ old('codigopostal', $cliente->codigopostal) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Dirreción del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="direccion" value="{{ old('direccion', $cliente->direccion) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Localidad del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="localidad" value="{{ old('localidad', $cliente->localidad) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Provincia del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="provincia" value="{{ old('provincia', $cliente->provincia) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Pais del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="pais" value="{{ old('pais', $cliente->pais) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Email<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email', $cliente->email) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Telefono del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="telefono" value="{{ old('telefono', $cliente->telefono) }}">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="carclientes/calculaedad.js"></script>
<br>
<br>

    <br>
    <br>
<div class="form-group">

    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Nombre completo del tutol del menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="nombrecompletome" value="{{ old('nombrecompletome', $cliente->nombrecompletome) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Direccion del tutol del menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="direccionme" value="{{ old('direccionme', $cliente->direccionme) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Localidad del tutol del menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="localidadme" value="{{ old('localidadme', $cliente->localidadme) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Provincia del tutol del menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="provinciame" value="{{ old('provinciame', $cliente->provinciame) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>País del tutol del menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="paisme" value="{{ old('paisme', $cliente->paisme) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Email del tutol del menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="emailme" value="{{ old('emailme', $cliente->emailme) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Telefono del tutol del menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="telefonome" value="{{ old('telefonome', $cliente->telefonome) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Vinculación del tutol con el menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="vinculacionconmenor" value="{{ old('vinculacionconmenor', $cliente->vinculacionconmenor) }}">


</div>
</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">{{$btnText}}</button>
    <a class="btn btn-link btn-block btn-danger btn-lg" href="{{ route('cliente.index')}}">Cancelar</a>
```

Para sacar la diferencia entre las dos fechas he de poner esto:

```
let fechana= $("#fechana").val();
```

Lo único que sé es que he de utilizar JQuery para esconder la parte del formulario que no necesito si la persona es mayor de edad que para ello utilizo(para esconderlo):

```
$("#datos_tutor").css("display","none");
```

Y para que se visualice:

```
$("#datos_tutor").css("display","block");
```

También sé que he de encerrar la parte del formulario que no quiero que se visualice en un `div`:

```
<div id="datos_tutor">.... formulario del tutor .... </div>
```

Tengo toda la sintaxis más o menos pero no sé dónde colocarla para que funcione correctamente.
[image: IMAGEN DEL FORMULARIO, después de añadir ahí una fecha quiero que si es menor de edad(menor de 18 años) se implemente el resto del formulario]

Comment: Donde ponerla dependerá de cuando quieres que se ejecute, en caso de que por ejemplo la recibas de un `<input>` donde le pasas la fecha, puede que quieras que se ejecute cada vez que el valor de la fecha cambie, pero si la estás trayendo de una base de datos, tendrás que ejecutarlo cuando sepas la edad. ¿Cuando quieres que se ejecute?

Comment: Pues la recibo a través del input y luego la almaceno en una base de datos pero quiero que se ejecute cuando ponga la fecha(en el input) y la diferencia sea menor de 18.

Comment: He insertado una foto para explicarme mejor

Comment: Lo del evento para el input de la fecha va bien, sólo una aclaración: En blade, cuando necesitas que se cargue algún otro script o librería (como jquery) antes de tu script, suelen usarse [@stacks](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#stacks)

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ pero si quisiera implementar el javascript dentro de mi HTML también debería usar los stacks o poniendo esto dentro de mi formulario valdría:

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
 function calculateAge(birthday) {
    var birthday_arr = birthday.split("/");
    var birthday_date = new Date(birthday_arr[2], birthday_arr[1] - 1, birthday_arr[0]);
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday_date.getTime();
    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs);
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}

var age = calculateAge("15/04/1976");
alert( age );
let fechana= $("#fechana").val();
</script>`

Comment: Como estás usando jquery, tendrías que asegurarte de que ya esté cargado. Con vanilla js tal vez no, pero es una "buena" práctica cargar el js al final

Comment: Okey, pero las funciones de jquery:
`$("#datos_tutor").css("display","none");`
`$("#datos_tutor").css("display","block");`
¿Dónde deberían de ir implementadas?
Dentro de la función de JavaScript o dentro de un div, es que nunca he usado mucho JQuery. Perdón por molestar @porloscerrosΨ y muchísimas gracias aprendo mucho aquí

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de distintas maneras, pero todas son bastantes parecidas, en caso de que quieras añadir el JS en el HTML, puedes ponerle al `input` de la fecha un `onchange` para llamar a una función que haga lo que deseas, pero si por otra parte, no quieres meter código JS en tu HTML, puedes utilizar `addEventListener`, para que llame a la función, estando todo en tu ficher JS. En vez de utilizar onchange, podrias utilizar otras como: onkeypress, onkeydown, onkeyup. La que mas te convenga

**DESDE EL HTML**

```
<input onchange="funcion()" id="fecha">

<script>

    function funcion(){
       //COMPARAS LA EDAD Y HACES LO QUE NECESITES
    }

</script>
```

**DESDE EL JAVASCRIPT**

```
fecha = document.getElementById("fecha"); //EL ID QUE TENGA TU INPUT

fecha.addEventListener("change", funcion);

function funcion(){
       //COMPARAS LA EDAD Y HACES LO QUE NECESITES
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la solución, he implementado lo que dijiste pero no he podido pegarla porque no dice que es demasiado larga e incumple el número máximo de caracteres @Maidagan

Comment: Si he solucionado parte de la incidencia pero me gustaría saber donde pongo los JQuery para que se vea o no el formulario porque no tengo muy claro como debería de hacerlo, es decir, si ponerlo dentro del <script>...function...</script> o en otro lugar o debo de poner algún 'if' y dentro de estos los JQuery o no sé. No sé si podrás ayudarme pero muchas gracias por la ayuda de antes. Ya tienes marcada la respuesta @Maidagan

Comment: Mi recomendación sería que creases un fichero .js, en el que añadas todo el código que necesitas, y luego dentro de tu `html`, antes de cerrar la etiqueta `</body>`, llames a este fichero.

Comment: Pero y los JQuery dónde los pongo @Maildagan? El fichero.js:
`fecha = document.getElementById("fechana");
fecha.addEventListener("change", calculateAge);
function calculateAge(birthday) {
    var birthday_arr = birthday.split("/");
    var birthday_date = new Date(birthday_arr[2], birthday_arr[1] - 1, birthday_arr[0]);
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday_date.getTime();
    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs);
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}

var age = calculateAge("15/04/1976");
alert( age );
let fechana= $("#fechana").val();`